# ansible sns - why is subscriber optional

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

When I am subscribing a lambda function to an SNS topic through either the aws console or aws cli there is a column shown in the subscription information called "subscriber". It does contain my account id.

I don't seem to be able to control this field through the cli or console however I can through ansible:

```
---
- name: set up topic and subscribe lambda
  sns_topic:
      name: "topic_name"
      state: present
      display_name: "Display Name"
      subscriptions:
        - endpoint: "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:123456789:function:functionName"
          protocol: "lambda"
          subscriber: 123456789
```

The subscriber field is optional, however SNS messages do not seem to reach lambda without it.

- What is this field for?
- Can I subscribe Lambdas in other accounts to my SNS topic?
- How can I effect change in this field with AWS CLI?
- Why is it optional in Ansible 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find reference to ghost field i.e. subscriber.
Maybe it was supported in older sdk/api and now has been dropped.

Reseach:

1. I don't see subscriber field in the console when subscribing lambda. Image below

[image]

2. Even through CLI, there is no such field
   [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/subscribe.html) for SNS Subscribe command through CLI documentation.

[Extra Research]: Even the java sdk asks for only three parameters in order to subscribe

```
 subscribe(String topicArn, String protocol, String endpoint)
```

Java doc [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#subscribe-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I'm using Ansible 2.3.0.0 and this is the code, however I cannot find a corresponding branch or tag for 2.3.0.0 https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/stable-2.2/cloud/amazon/sns_topic.py#L3

I certainly can reproduce that if I am not passing the subscriber field, my subscription doesn't work

Comment: Maybe I need to raise this as a bug with Ansible

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was up to date, but upgrading to Ansible 2.4.3.0-1 solves the problem. No subscriber dict entry required anymore

Comment: Great awesome! :)